# Determining FOLLOW sets of CFG

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar

On [this page](http://web.cs.dal.ca/~sjackson/lalr1.html) the author explains how to determine the FOLLOW sets of a CFG. Under the headline **Syntax Analysis Goal: FOLLOW Sets** he states:

> Steps to Make the Follow Set
>
> Conventions: a, b, and c represent a terminal or non-terminal. a*
>   represents zero or more terminals or non-terminals (possibly both). a+
>   represents one or more... D is a non-terminal.
>
> 1. Place an End of Input token ($) into the starting rule's follow set.
> 2. Suppose we have a rule R → a*Db. Everything in First(b) (except for ε)
>      is added to Follow(D). If First(b) contains ε then everything in
>      Follow(R) is put in Follow(D).
> 3. Finally, if we have a rule R → a*D,
>      then everything in Follow(R) is placed in Follow(D).
> 4. The Follow set of
>      a terminal is an empty set.

So far so good. But in the box below this item, we read:

> [...] Step 2 on rule 1 (N → V = E) indicates that first(=) is in Follow(V).

Now this is the part I don't understand. When he says that First(=) is in Follow (V), he obviously maps = to b and V to D (b and D from the explication in the first box). But `(a*)(D)(b)` does not match `()(V)(=)E`.

**Am I reading this completely wrong, or did the author maybe write `a*Db` instead of `a*Dba*`?**

(Especially if you read this on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_LR_parser): "FOLLOW(I) of an Item I [A → α • B β, x] is the set of terminals that can appear after nonterminal B, where α, β are arbitrary symbol strings, and x is an arbitrary lookahead terminal.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, he meant:

`R → a* D b*`

and since `b*` could be zero symbols, i.e. ε, the second rule is unneeded. Remember that `FIRST` is defined on arbitrary sequences of symbols.

In other words, for:

`A → α B β`

1. Every terminal in `FIRST(β)` is in `FOLLOW(B)`, and
2. If `β ⇒* ε`, then everything in `FOLLOW(A)` is in `FOLLOW(B)`.

Here's what Aho, Sethi & Ullman say in the dragon book:

> Formally, we say `LR(1)` item `[A → α·β, a]` is *valid* for a viable prefix γ if there is a derivation
>  `S ⇒* δAw ⇒ δαβw`
>   where `γ = δα` and either `a` is the first symbol of `w` or `w` is ε and `a` is `$`.

(The `⇒`'s above are marked `rm`, meaning `right-most derivation`; in other words, in every derivation step, the right-most non-terminal is substituted with one of its productions. Consequently, `w` only contains terminals.)

In other words, the `LR(1)` item is *valid* (could apply) if we've reached some point where we've decided that `A` might be the next reduction and `a` might follow `A`; at the current point in the parse, we've read α. So *if* `a` follows β, then the reduction is possible. We don't yet know that, unless β is the empty sequence, but we need to remember the fact in case it turns out that β can *derive* the empty sequence.

I hope that helps. It's late here and I'm too tired to check it again. Maybe tomorrow...